at what age does obligation starts on a boy? does it start on age 15
like touching and as we know that women's can take of their hijab in front of small kids as their kids but not in front of big boys.at what age does a boy cannot touch a girl anymore.

You are asking two different questions. Obligations start at adulthood but hijab in front of them starts before that. In general if they know about sexual matters or can feel desire then they must be veiled from. See  Quran 24:58 , Quran 24:31

Please avoid asking multiple questions in one post.

Alhamdulillah,
You have asked two questions:
Question 1 is "at what age does obligation starts"
The age when religious obligations start for a boy (as well as a girl) is determined by the criterion of buloogh (puberty).
Most scholars agree that buloogh begins at the age of 15 lunar years for both boys and girls. However, there are also other physical signs that indicate the onset of puberty, such as:

Ejaculation of semen (through a wet dream or otherwise)
Menstruation
Growth of coarse pubic hair around the private parts
Pregnancy

If any of these physical signs appear before the age of 15, it is considered that the child has reached buloogh and all religious obligations become binding upon them.
Conversely, if none of these signs are seen by the age of 15, scholars still consider a person to have reached buloogh and religious accountability begins at that age.
So in summary:

The default age for religious obligations to start is 15 lunar years for both boys and girls.
However, if signs of puberty appear earlier, obligations start from that point.
If no signs appear even after 15, the person is still considered to have reached buloogh at 15.

As for Question 2 which is "at what age does a boy cannot touch a girl anymore?"
This is answered here in Arabic
a non-discerning (ghair mumayyiz) child does not require a woman to observe hijab/covering from him. Ibn Qudamah said in Al-Mughni: "As for a boy, as long as he is a child lacking discernment, a woman is not obligated to observe hijab from him in anything."
However, if he has reached the age of discernment (mumayyiz) but is not yet at the age of puberty, some scholars view him like a mahram (unmarriageable kin) in terms of looking at a woman. So he is allowed to look at what is normally visible like the neck, head, hands and feet. This is one of the two opinions attributed to Imam Ahmad as mentioned in Al-Mughni.
If the child is a pre-adolescent (murahiq), meaning he is approaching the age of puberty, then a woman is obligated to observe hijab from him. It is stated in Tuhfat Al-Muhtaj: "The more correct view is that a pre-adolescent (murahiq), which refers to one approaching the age of nocturnal emission - judged by his age, being close to fifteen not nine years old - is possibly not like an adult. So hijab becomes obligatory upon the woman from him, like from an insane person."
And Allah knows best!
